# Placeholder syntax limitations for parameters

Tags: scala

After having read the Programming in Scala book and searched a little, I still don't understand why this works:

```
val x = Array[Byte](1, 2, 3)
x.map{Integer.toHexString(_)}
```

whereas this other slightly more complicated one doesn't:

```
val x = Array[Byte](1, 2, 3)
x.map{Integer.toHexString((_ + 0x100) % 0x100)}
```

This longer alternative does work:

```
x.map{b => Integer.toHexString((b + 0x100) % 0x100)}
```

This is the obscure error message I get:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$plus(256))
```

I'm using:

- Exactly one _ for each existing parameter
- Not using any inner anonymous function.

Are the parenthesis harmful?

Comment: I don't have a reference for this, so I won't add it as an answer. In general, an `_` can only refer to a param in the closest wrapping set of paratheses. The only exception is the one you've mentioned, where the expression wrapped is just an `_`. If the `_` occurs inside a more complex expression, the compiler will consider it as a placeholder for the first wrapping set of parantheses.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to avoid using _ in complex functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec is [this section](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions).

The intuition of "something complex" is the bit about "syntactic category Expr", as opposed to a "SimpleExpr", which you can review [about half-way through the syntax section](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/13-syntax-summary.html).

You can see there that the things inside parens are Exprs, so that's why people approximate the syntax by saying, "It expands to the innermost parens."

You can often avoid incurring an Expr by using infix notation. But your operator precedence has to help.

```
scala> (1 to 5) map ("x" * _)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(x, xx, xxx, xxxx, xxxxx)

scala> (1 to 5) map ("x".*(_))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(x, xx, xxx, xxxx, xxxxx)

scala> (1 to 5) map ("x".*(_ + 5))
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$plus(5))
              (1 to 5) map ("x".*(_ + 5))
                                  ^

scala> (1 to 5) map ("x" * _ + 5)
res5: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(x5, xx5, xxx5, xxxx5, xxxxx5)
```

Compare with:

```
scala> (1 to 5) map ("abcdefg" apply _)
res8: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(b, c, d, e, f)

scala> (1 to 5) map ("abcdefg" apply _ + 1)
res9: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(c, d, e, f, g)

scala> (1 to 5) map ("abcdefg".apply(_ + 1))
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1))
              (1 to 5) map ("abcdefg".apply(_ + 1))
                                            ^

scala> (1 to 5) map ("abcdefg"(_ + 1))
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1))
              (1 to 5) map ("abcdefg"(_ + 1))
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 2):

The rather precise but not very helpful answer is: "That's the appropriate behaviour according to [the Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)" (Note: I didn't actually check that)

Less precise, but more helpful might be the insight, that the second example actually is way more complicated.

In the first example you have one function (actually a method that gets converted to a function) with one input parameter of unknown type and an output parameter of unknown type, that has to be matched to the arguments of map (note that there are implicit arguments you don't see, making this task already non trivial):

In the second example you have a

function + 0x100

of which the result gets passed to a function % 0x100

of which the result gets passed to a function Integer.toHexString

and while you don't intend to use an inner anonymous function (_ + 0x100) might actually be one. The compiler can't be sure.